# ASP.NET 5: Access-Control-Allow-Origin in response

Tags: c#, cors, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-mvc

From what I understand, when enabled CORS accordingly, the response model should include the following header information (provided that I want to allow everything):

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Method: *
Access-Control-Allow-Header: *
```

Enabling it in `Startup`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //...
    services.AddCors();
    services.ConfigureCors(options => 
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", p => p.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials());
    });
    //...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    //...
    app.UseCors("AllowAll");
    //...
}
```

The problem is that none of these headers are returned and I get the following error when trying to request from the API:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Does this error comes in chrome console ?

Comment: did you register the Cors middleware before MVC middleware? can you share more info on your `Configure` method?

Comment: As Kiran said, this won't work if you have added `app.UseCors` after `app.UseMvc` in your `Startup.Configure` method. You need to add the Cors middleware before the MVC middleware. (By the way, in RC1 there is no `ConfigureCors` method anymore and the options can be passed directly into the `AddCors` method)

Comment: @DanielJ.G., the correct order (`app.UseCors` before `app.UseMvc`) did the trick for me. Please add this as answer so I can upvote it :) Thanks! This is annoying since it is not mentioned in the [latest docs](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/cors.html).

Comment: I have not ***app.UseMvc()***

Only: 
```app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>            {               endpoints.MapControllers();            });```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Make sure you add `app.UseCors` before `app.UseMvc` in your `Startup.Configure` method, because you need the CORS middleware to be applied before the MVC middleware.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    ...

    //Add CORS middleware before MVC
    app.UseCors("AllowAll");

    app.UseMvc(...);
}
```

Otherwise the request will be finished before the CORS middleware is applied. This is because [`UseMvc`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/82381d97c2950d3ae41d0baf2cd9c78964bcb776/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/Builder/MvcApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs) calls [`UseRouter`](https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/blob/9b217a4026b8ff9ff4e9ff3365cd53c622d4c6bf/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Routing/BuilderExtensions.cs) which ends up adding the [`RouterMiddleware`](https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/blob/6e8b2ecd632315c56e94bc60906d796a25dce256/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Routing/RouterMiddleware.cs), and this middleware only executes the next configured middleware when a route handler wasn't found for the request.

Comment: Wow this helped. Our `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)` was abstracted into a base class. So we were call `app.UseCors` after calling base class.

Answer (score 3):

In .Net Core Web API 5.0 in `Configure` method you have to add `app.UseCors` before other methods, like that:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        ...
    }

    //add CORS
    app.UseCors();

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

Comment: You sure about that? "System.InvalidOperationException: Endpoint {app_name}.Web.Controllers.PageController.GetPageListing ({app_name}) contains CORS metadata, but a middleware was not found that supports CORS.
Configure your application startup by adding app.UseCors() inside the call to Configure(..) in the application startup code. The call to app.UseCors() must appear between app.UseRouting() and app.UseEndpoints(...)" in a .Net Core Web API 5.0 application.