# ASP.NET Core CORS WebAPI: no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Tags: c#, azure, angular, asp.net-core, cors

I have deployed my ASP.NET Core web API to Azure, and I can access its endpoints using Swagger or a web debugger like Fiddler. In both cases (same origin in Swagger, different origin using Fiddler from my computer), when accessing the APIs I get the expected result, with CORS enabled as follows in my `Startup.cs`:

1. add `services.AddCors();` to `ConfigureServices`.
2. add the middleware to `Configure`: I'm aware that order here matters ([ASP.NET 5: Access-Control-Allow-Origin in response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34065588/asp-net-5-access-control-allow-origin-in-response)), so I am placing this call at the top of the method, only preceded by logging or diagnostic middleware; here is my full method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
    IDatabaseInitializer databaseInitializer)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();
    loggerFactory.AddNLog();

    // to serve up index.html
    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    // http://www.talkingdotnet.com/aspnet-core-diagnostics-middleware-error-handling/
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();

    // CORS
    // https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/cors.html
    app.UseCors(builder =>
            builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "http://www.myclientserver.com")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod());

    app.UseOAuthValidation();
    app.UseOpenIddict();
    app.UseMvc();

    databaseInitializer.Seed().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    env.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");

    // swagger
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUi();
}
```

The `localhost` CORS is used during development, and refers to an Angular2 CLI app. CORS is working fine locally, and my client and API apps are on different ports on the same localhost, so this is "true" cross origin (I'm remarking this because of the suggestions I found here: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Sep/26/ASPNET-Core-and-CORS-Gotchas: the author of the post notices that the CORS header in the response is sent *only* when actually required, i.e. in true cross-origin environments).

Using Fiddler I can succesfully access the remote API, but I get NO `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. Thus, when calling the API from the browser (through my client app) the AJAX request fails, even if the server returns 200. Sample Fiddler request (success):

```
GET http://mywebapisiteurl/api/values HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
```

response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=3d551180c72208c1d997584c2b6119cf44e3a55c868f05ffc9258d25a58e95b1;Path=/;Domain=prinapi.azurewebsites.net
Date: Thu, 01 Dec 2016 10:30:19 GMT

["value1","value2"]
```

When trying to access the remote API deployed on Azure, my client app always fails its AJAX request with error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.myclientserver.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Here is a sample client code using Angular2 (using Plunker):

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <button (click)="test()">test</button>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor(private _http: Http) {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
  public test() {
    this._http.get('http://theapisiteurlhere/api/values',
    {
        headers: new Headers({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        })
    })
    .subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        console.log(data);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, HttpModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

To sum up, it seems that the ASPNET API server is not returning the expected CORS headers, and thus my browser-based client hosted on a different origin fails. Yet, the CORS setup seems to be OK, at least judging from the documentation quoted above; I'm in true cross-origin environment; and I'm placing the middleware before the others. Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but googling around these are all the recommendations I found. Any hint?

**UPDATE**

In reply to @Daniel J.G: the request/response from fiddler are successful:

```
GET http://theapiserver/api/values HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: theapiserver
Origin: http://theappserver/apps/prin
```

and:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://theappserver/apps/prin
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=3d551180c72208c1d997584c2b6119cf44e3a55c868f05ffc9258d25a58e95b1;Path=/;Domain=theapiserver
Date: Thu, 01 Dec 2016 14:15:21 GMT
Content-Length: 19

["value1","value2"]
```

The request/response from Angular2 (Plunker) instead fail, as reported. By inspecting the network traffic, I can see the preflight request only:

```
OPTIONS http://theapiserver/api/values HTTP/1.1
Host: theapiserver
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://run.plnkr.co
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://run.plnkr.co/h17wYofXGFuTy2Oh/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,it;q=0.6

HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=3d551180c72208c1d997584c2b6119cf44e3a55c868f05ffc9258d25a58e95b1;Path=/;Domain=theapiserver
Date: Thu, 01 Dec 2016 14:23:02 GMT
```

After this, the request fails and no more traffic goes to the server. The reported issue is that `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check`, again because of lack of the header in the response:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://theapiserver/api/values. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://run.plnkr.co' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: Have you tried in fiddler setting the host and origin headers (host to the api host and origin to a different one to simulate cross origin)? It might also help if you post the details of a rquest made from angular.

Comment: Thank you, I updated my post (see at the bottom). In short, using Fiddler it's OK; using Angular2, the preflight request fails because there is no ACAO header in the server response, despite CORS being enabled.

Comment: You sure the origin `http://run.plnkr.co` is one of the allowed origins?

Comment: Guys, found the solution: I had not noticed that in Azure portal there is a CORS section. If I don't enter any allowed origin there, my code-based configuration seems to be totally irrelevant. This looks odd to me, as I'm forced to duplicate URLs here, but once I added * to the allowed origins there it worked.

Comment: I guess Azure sits in front of your app and does its own CORS check

Comment: putting same thing into cors on azure solved it for me as well. damn.

Comment: @Naftis, it's better to put what you found into a separate answer and mark it as the answer of this question. Otherwise it's hard to notice the reason of this issue in the comments.

Comment: I'm also having this issue but not using Azure...asp.net core running as a windows service.  Code base has everything like the OP's with regard to CORS.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is the answer to my own question, copied from the comments: I had not noticed that in **Azure portal** there is a CORS section. If I don't enter any allowed origin there, my code-based configuration seems to be totally irrelevant. This looks odd to me, as I'm forced to duplicate URLs here, but once I added `*` to the allowed origins there it worked.

Comment: For interested readers, this is a newer minimal sample for the password flow using OpenIdDict rc 3, which got some API changes: https://github.com/Myrmex/oid-credentials. Pay attention to the [Authorize] attribute parameter (end note in readme).

Comment: I've not tested but if this is true, what's the point of having CORS config in the code? thanks Naftis for pointing it out :)

Comment: You just saved me hours of troubleshooting!  Thank you!  I appreciate that MS is allowing CORS configuration in the Azure Portal, but it's frustrating that it's not more obvious.  This seems to completely override the code-based CORS config (as others have said)...

Comment: this is un neccessary., you can use app.UseCors

Comment: I added * to allowed origins, but now my POST requests generate 500 errors, both in my Angular app and Postman tests

Comment: This seems to be fixed now. I can leave the CORS section blank and it honors my application settings. What I was doing wrong was adding them like this `http://www.example.com/`, which is wrong. You have to add them like this: `http://www.example.com` (without the tailing forward-slash)

Comment: Oh God, I have spent last 7 days on this issue and finally this post saved me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

I was facing similar error, but my error solved by keeping the pipeline in order. (startup.cs -> configureServices) like

```
  app.UseRouting();
  app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => .....
```

Comment: Thanks! that tip ended hours of head scratching & binge drinking!

Comment: Congrulations! I have tried everything but that point saved me

Answer (score 6):

Adding the .AllowAnyHeader() method could fix your problem

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                              .AllowAnyMethod()
                              .AllowAnyHeader());
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message is very mis-leading. I was getting the same error after trying to add a new table to the DbContext. Angular was giving the no "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error, but Postman was giving a 500 Internal Server error. The Login method was failing when trying to call _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(). Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: It certainly helped me! This deserves more prominence, I just spent half a day trying to debug what looked like a CORS error in the browser console before your comment reminded me that I had not yet deployed a particular database artifact to production, resulting in an exception in the API server. I definitely need to find a way to surface those errors more accurately via the Swagger/NSwag combination I am using.

Answer (score -4):

WebApi Project ---> Right click on References ---> Search Core in Manage Nuget Packages section. Add Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors to the project by installing

Add the following code to the WebApi.Config file under the App_Start folder in the project.

var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*","*","*");
config.EnableCors(cors);

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dV0cJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIOaU.png)

Comment: The OP is asking about ASP.NET CORE, not ASP.NET