# Rest API getting CORS when accessing through client

Tags: .net, reactjs, asp.net-core, cors

Can you help me out? I am currently stuck on solving this problem. I created a .Net Core Rest API that is hosted in Azure. I am using that rest API using my reactjs application. Whenever I try to access it's giving me this error.

[image]

And here is my rest API startup.cs

[image]

Below is my ReactApplication
[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Note: the URL where my reactjs application is located is "https://clienturl.com"

Comment: Have you added the CORS middleware in the Configure method in Startup also?

Comment: Before hosting the web application to Azure, whether the request success or not? I found a thread, it seems that in Azure portal there is a CORS section, try to check it in Azure, make sure it allowed the related origins. Reference: [ASP.NET Core CORS WebAPI: no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40908949/asp-net-core-cors-webapi-no-access-control-allow-origin-header)

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), which means that a resource in a domain name A can't access another resource in domain name B without prior permission.
You can give enable CORS for your frontend app in the backend server, or if it's just for development use this [plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en)

Comment: am... Sorry but I don't think installing a plugin is a good option. Was wondering if I can find a solution that I just need to fix something in my code

Comment: your code is fine you just need to enable CORS in the API server as I suggested, please take a look at the link I shared.